# Does there exist standardized language-agnostic data structure notation?

Tags: data-structures, notation

I wonder if there exists language-agnostic data structure notation. Preferably a standard, allowing to describe data structures and basic data types. e.g. something like a subset of `WebIDL`.

A motivation is to describe data structures (a model) in a way that is standardized and language-agnostic. Then have a set of mappings of those data structures into various representations (`XML`, `JSON`, `YAML`)

Comment: (XML doesn't exclude *(programming) language agnostic* in my book.)

Comment: @greybeard Thank you, but the question is not about XML capabilities. Let's suppose I want to use XML to represent just data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of notation:

- Isn't [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) exactly what you are looking for? (barring all the "[severe criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)#Criticism)" ...). Also not sure if you are looking for a notation convenient to hand-write, that's certainly NOT XML :-).
- [Typedefs](https://typedefs.com/) and [preserves](https://preserves.gitlab.io/preserves) seem to have more of a mathematical basis, perhaps closer to what you are looking for. A related [HN thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24972271).

I suspect you already know a lot of these projects, usually the focus is in serialization:

- The [IDL list at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) ...
- Amazon's [Smithy](https://awslabs.github.io/smithy/) and [Ion](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/).
- Microsoft's [Bond](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/).
- And of course Google's [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) and [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/), but also [Mojo](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/mojo/), oriented to IPC, and [Fuchsia FIDL](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/languages/fidl) which seems similar.

Investigating this space I found [Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/), "a language-independent columnar memory format" for sharing memory between programs, with libraries for a dozen of languages. Turns out it uses [flatbuffers under the hood](https://arrow.apache.org/faq/#how-does-arrow-relate-to-flatbuffers).

Now that I came up with this list and I suspect you may be familiar with a lot of them, perhaps will be useful to know in which way the thing you are looking for is different. I think the keyword "**notation**" on your question is the key.

Cheers!

Comment: That's a great summary! Thank you.